# Non-interactive job parameters for Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We're setting up Jenkins with Kubernetes plugin, using pipelines to run the jobs. Suppose I have a pipeline with my Maven build, and I want to run it with JDK 11 and JDK 17. The pipeline is virtually the same, the only difference is the container image I need to use, e.g. `maven:3.8.5-openjdk-11-slim` for JDK 11. I can replace this with `"${MAVEN_IMAGE}"` and add some parameter in the Jenkins job (e.g. choice, in job XML these reside inside `hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty` element), but this is not what I really want.

I'd like to set the parameter value non-interactively in the job, but I can't find any way how to do it. Is there some way how to get something like an environment variable from the job XML to the pipeline runtime environment?

There is one workaround I could use - I could choose the right thing in the pipeline based on something like `JOB_BASE_NAME` - but that puts a logic into the pipeline that I really don't want there - it would decide on hardcoded names of the jobs and also the container can only be changed in the pipeline.

(I do realize, that from CI/CD and repeatability perspective it's better to leave the container name inside, but that's not my concern currently.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way how to provide non-interactive parameters to the pipeline, but it is easy to make the parameter optional and provide the default value using Groovy syntax in the pipeline. For example, if used inside a GString:

```
"${params.BUILDER_IMAGE ?: 'maven:3.8.5-openjdk-11-slim'}"
```

The use of `params` is crucial, using `BUILDER_IMAGE` directly would fail with a missing script property error, but accessing it via `params` map returns `null` and falls back to the constant provided after the Elvis operator `?:`.

This is still sub-optimal because the parameter to provide the different value is still interactive and requires another confirmation click, but it allows to provide the value only if different from some default. Also, the default value is in the pipeline. I doubt this is the state of the art in Jenkins pipelines, but I can't find a better way yet.